# Reinforcement learning example (chap. 1) from Sutton's book

Tags: haskell, lisp, machine-learning

I ported the [Lisp Tic Tac Toe code](http://lpaste.net/354002) from Chapter 1. to Haskell. [The original code repo](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/code/TTT.lisp) is down for some reason.

I believe I have completely rewritten that in Haskell (Less functional than one would expect ). It is being tested. But I have doubts about how the learning algorithm learns. I see this type of result from my code which is the equivalent of the 'run' function in the book.

```
"Played 100 times 43.5  0.435"
"Played 100 times 46.0  0.46"
"Played 100 times 42.0  0.42"
"Played 100 times 41.0  0.41"
```

`numruns` and `playrepeatedly` in my code are the equivalent of `runs` in the Lisp example.

There are two players, X and O. Since I write some log files I can see that Player X wins many times. I thought eventually Player O will observe, learn and start winning. Since I am yet to run the algorithm hundreds of times, I don't see Player O winning. Please point out anything wrong in my assumption.

My code compiles and prints the result, so trivial bugs aren't there, I think. But `gameplan`, my largest function, could have a bug or two, but I'm not sure.

Can anyone review from the perspective of improving the learning of the algorithm? There may be a code bug that prevents it from learning properly.

Please ignore Haskell Gloss code. That was used to view the board, so it's useless now.

```
  module ReinforcementLearning where
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Applicative
import Graphics.Gloss
import Data.Array.IO
import Control.Monad.Reader
import System.Random
import Data.List
import Control.Exception
import System.IO.Error 
import Text.Printf
import Debug.Trace
import System.IO

fun :: Map.Map String Int
fun = Map.empty


store :: String -> Int-> State (Map.Map String Int) ()
store x value = do
  fun <- get
  put (Map.insert x value fun)

retrieve :: String -> State (Map.Map String Int) (Maybe (Int))
retrieve roworcolumn = do
  fun <- get
  return (Map.lookup roworcolumn fun) 


getrow = do {store "row" 1; retrieve "row"}  
getcolumn = do {store "column" 1; retrieve "column"}  
getboardsize = do   
           let x = (runState getrow fun) in
             let y = (runState getcolumn fun) in
                (Just (*) <*> (fst x)  <*>  (fst y) )

magicsquare :: [Int]
magicsquare = [2,9,4,7,5,4,7,5,4] 

data BoardState = BoardState { xloc :: [Int],
                               oloc :: [Int],
                               index :: Int
                             }  deriving (Show)

translationaccumulator ::   [Int] -> [Int] -> [(Float,Float)] -> [Picture] -> [Picture]
translationaccumulator  [] _ _ ys = reverse ys
translationaccumulator  _ []  _ ys = reverse ys
translationaccumulator  (head1:xs1) (head:xs) angle  ys = let (a,b) = (angle !!(head - 1)) in
                                                            let (c,d) = (angle  !!(head1 - 1)) in
                                                              translationaccumulator xs1 xs angle ( ((translate a b) $
                                                                                                 drawx ) : ((translate c d) $
                                                                                                 drawo ):ys)

drawBoard :: BoardState -> Picture
drawBoard (BoardState xloc oloc index)=
  Pictures $ [ translate x y $ rectangleWire 90 90| x<-[0,90..180], y<-[0,90..180] ] ++ (translationaccumulator xloc oloc [(0,180),(90,180),(180,180),(0,90),(90,90),(180,90),(0,0),(90,0),(180,0)] [])

drawx :: Picture
drawx = color green $ rotate 45 $
        pictures [rectangleWire 1 45, rectangleWire  45 1] 

drawo :: Picture
drawo = color rose $ thickCircle 25 2

powersof2  :: [Int]  
powersof2  =  [ 2 ^ i | i <- [0..8]]


createarray :: IO ( IOArray Int Double)
createarray =  do {
                       arr <- newArray (0,512*512) (-1.0);
                       return arr
                  }

addVal :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
addVal i [] = []
addVal i (x:xs) = x * 512: addVal i xs

stateindex :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int
stateindex xloc oloc = sum (map (2^) xloc)
                       + sum [2^n | n <- (addVal 512 oloc)]

type ArrayAccess = ReaderT  (IOArray Int Double)  IO 
type ArrayWriteAccess = ReaderT  (IOArray Int Double)  IO() 

readvalue ::  Int -> ArrayAccess  Double  
readvalue x    = do 
  a <- ask
  b <- liftIO( readArray a x);    
  return b

writevalue ::  Int -> Double -> ArrayWriteAccess   
writevalue x y   = do 
  a <- ask
  liftIO( writeArray a x y)    

-- Test array accesses
readfromarray = do { a <- createarray; liftIO (runReaderT (readvalue 1) a) }
writetoarray = do { a <- createarray; liftIO (runReaderT (writevalue 1 2) a) }

logs      ::  String -> IO ()
logs  message = withFile "c:/Git/game.log" AppendMode (\ fd -> hPrint fd message )

logsresult      ::  String -> IO ()
logsresult  message = withFile "c:/Git/learning.log" AppendMode (\ fd -> hPrint fd message )

playero ::  String -> IO ()
playero message = withFile "c:/Git/playero.log" AppendMode (\ fd -> hPrint fd message )

showstate :: BoardState -> IO ()
showstate (BoardState xloc oloc index) = display (InWindow "Reinforcement Learning" (530,530) (220,220)) (greyN 0.5)  (drawBoard (BoardState xloc oloc index) )

data Player = X | O deriving Show
isX :: Player -> Bool
isX X = True
isX O = False 

type StateValue sv = StateT BoardState IO sv

append :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
append elem l = if elem == 0 then l else l ++ [elem]

readthevalue :: ( IOArray Int Double) -> Int -> IO Double
readthevalue a index =  liftIO (runReaderT (readvalue index ) a) 

writethevalue :: ( IOArray Int Double) -> Int -> Double -> IO ()
writethevalue a index value =  liftIO (runReaderT (writevalue index value) a)  

nextstate :: Player -> BoardState -> Int -> BoardState
-- nextstate  player (BoardState xloc oloc index) move= traceShowId $  BoardState newx newo newindex where
nextstate  player (BoardState xloc oloc index) move=  BoardState newx newo newindex where
  newx = if isX player then (append move xloc) else xloc
  newo = if isX player then (append move oloc) else oloc
  newindex = stateindex newx newo

magicnumber :: [Int]-> Int
magicnumber l = sum $ ([magicsquare !! (x-1) | x <- l, x > 0])


nextvalue :: (String -> IO()) -> Player -> Int -> ( IOArray Int Double) -> BoardState-> IO (BoardState,IOArray Int Double) 
nextvalue log player move a ( BoardState xloc oloc index) =  do
  let newstate = (nextstate player ( BoardState xloc oloc index) move)
  x <- catch (readthevalue a (ReinforcementLearning.index newstate))(\(SomeException e) -> printf "Reading [%d} in Next value" index >> print e >> throwIO e)
  log $ printf "Move is [%d] Value from value table is %f" move x
  log $ (show player)
  log $ show (ReinforcementLearning.xloc newstate)
  log $ show (ReinforcementLearning.oloc newstate)
  if (x == -1.0)
  then if ((magicnumber (ReinforcementLearning.xloc newstate)) == 15)
       then do
            (writethevalue a (ReinforcementLearning.index newstate) 0)
            log $ printf "Magic number is %d. Player X wins" (magicnumber  (ReinforcementLearning.xloc newstate))
            return (newstate,a)
       else if ((magicnumber (ReinforcementLearning.oloc newstate)) == 15)
            then do
                 (writethevalue a  (ReinforcementLearning.index newstate) 1)
                 playero $ printf "Magic number is %d. Player O wins" (magicnumber  (ReinforcementLearning.oloc newstate))
                 return (newstate,a)
            else if ((length (ReinforcementLearning.oloc newstate))+(length (ReinforcementLearning.xloc newstate)) == 9)
            then do
                 playero $ printf "Sume of Length of states is 9"
                 (writethevalue a  (ReinforcementLearning.index newstate) 0)
                 return (newstate,a)
            else do
                 (writethevalue a  (ReinforcementLearning.index newstate) 0.5)
                 return (newstate,a)
  else return (newstate,a)

--   Returns a list of unplayed locations
possiblemoves :: BoardState -> [Int]
possiblemoves (BoardState xloc oloc index) =
  let xs =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] in
    (xs \\ xloc) \\ oloc

debug :: IO Int -> IO Int
debug value = do
  x <- value
  return x

--   "Returns one of the unplayed locations, selected at random"
randommove ::  BoardState -> IO Int
randommove state = 
  let possibles = possiblemoves state in
    case possibles of
      [] -> return 0
      p -> debug $ fmap (p !! ) $ randomRIO(0, length p - 1)
      -- p ->  fmap (p !! ) $ randomRIO(0, length p - 1)

update :: ( IOArray Int Double) -> BoardState -> BoardState -> IO ( IOArray Int Double)
update a state newstate = do
  valueofstate <- readthevalue a (ReinforcementLearning.index state)
  valueofnewstate <- readthevalue a (ReinforcementLearning.index newstate)

  let finalvalue = valueofstate + ( 0.5 *  (valueofnewstate - valueofstate)) in
  --  This is the learning rule
    writethevalue a (ReinforcementLearning.index state) finalvalue
  return a

randombetween :: IO Double
randombetween = do
  r1 <-  randomRIO(0, 1.0)
  return r1


terminalstatep :: (String -> IO()) ->( IOArray Int Double) -> Int -> IO Bool
terminalstatep log a x = do
  y <-  catch ( readthevalue a x) (\(SomeException e) ->  print e >> printf "Read in terminalstep throws exception" >> throwIO e)
  let result = (y == fromIntegral( round y))
  do {
    log $ printf "Terminal Step - Value is %f" y;
    return result
    }

greedymove ::  (String -> IO()) ->( IOArray Int Double) ->Player -> BoardState -> IO (Int,IOArray Int Double)
greedymove log a player state = 
  let possibles = possiblemoves state in
    case possibles of
      [] -> return (0, a)
      p  -> let bestvalue = -1.0 in
              let bestmove = 0 in
                choosebestmove a p bestvalue bestmove
                where
                  choosebestmove arr [] bestvalue1 bestmove1 = return (0,a)
                  choosebestmove arr (x:xs) bestvalue1 bestmove1 = do
                    (nv,b) <- nextvalue logs player x arr state
                    xvalue <-  catch (readthevalue b (ReinforcementLearning.index (nv)))(\(SomeException e) -> printf "Reading [%d} in greedy move" x >> print e >> throwIO e)
                    case compare bestvalue1 xvalue of
                      LT -> choosebestmove b xs xvalue x;
                      GT -> return (bestmove1,b)
                      EQ -> return (bestmove1,b)

randomgreedy :: (String -> IO()) ->Double -> Int -> Int -> Int
randomgreedy log r1 rm gm = if (r1 < 0.01)
                            then rm
                            else gm



gameplan :: (String -> IO()) ->( IOArray Int Double) -> BoardState -> BoardState -> IO (IOArray Int Double,BoardState,Double) 
gameplan log a state newstate = do 
  r1 <- randombetween;
  initialvalue <- readthevalue  a 0
  result <- (terminalstatep log a (ReinforcementLearning.index newstate));
    case result of
      True -> do
        b <- update a state newstate
        valueofnewstate <- catch (readthevalue b (ReinforcementLearning.index newstate)) (\(SomeException e) -> print e >> mapM_ (putStr . show) [ (ReinforcementLearning.index newstate)]>> throwIO e)
        log $ printf "Gameplan returns(True branch) %f\n " valueofnewstate
        return (b,newstate,valueofnewstate)
      False -> do
        rm <- randommove newstate
        (gm,c) <- greedymove log a O newstate
        log $ printf "Greedy Move is %d \n " gm
        valueofnewstate <-  catch (readthevalue c (ReinforcementLearning.index newstate)) (\(SomeException e) -> print e >> mapM_ (putStr . show) [ (ReinforcementLearning.index newstate)]>> throwIO e)
        -- if (gm == 0)
        --   then do
        --   return(c,newstate,valueofnewstate)
        --   else do
        (nv,d) <- nextvalue logs O (randomgreedy log r1 rm gm) c newstate
        d' <- if r1 < 0.01 then return d else update d state nv
        result1 <- (terminalstatep log d' (ReinforcementLearning.index nv));
        valueofnewstate1 <-  catch (readthevalue d' (ReinforcementLearning.index nv)) (\(SomeException e) -> print e >> mapM_ (putStr . show) [ (ReinforcementLearning.index nv)]>> throwIO e)
        if (length (possiblemoves nv) == 0)
          then
          return (d',nv,valueofnewstate1)
          else if result1
               then do
               log $ printf "Gameplan returns(False branch) %f\n " valueofnewstate1
               return (d',nv,valueofnewstate1)
               else do
               r <- randommove newstate
               (nv1,d1') <- nextvalue logs X r d' newstate
               gameplan log d1' newstate (nv1)


--   "Plays 1 game against the random player. Also learns and prints.
--    :X moves first and is random.  :O learns"
game ::  (String -> IO()) ->BoardState  -> BoardState -> IOArray Int Double -> IO (IOArray Int Double,BoardState,Double) 
game log state newstate a  = do
  log $ "Call game"
  (newa, state, result )<-  gameplan log a state newstate
  return (newa, state, result )

playntimes :: IOArray Int Double -> (String -> IO()) ->Int -> IO (IOArray Int Double)
-- playntimes log n = do a <- createarray;
playntimes a log n = do writethevalue a 0 0.5
                        r <- (randommove (BoardState [] [] 0))
                        playtime  a (BoardState [] [] 0) (nextvalue logs X r a (BoardState [] [] 0)) n 0 r
                          where
                            playtime :: IOArray Int Double -> BoardState -> IO (BoardState,IOArray Int Double) -> Int -> Double -> Int -> IO (IOArray Int Double)
                            playtime newa s ns n acc r
                              | n == 0 = do logsresult $ printf "Played 100 times %f  %f"  acc (acc/100.0)
                                            return newa
                              | n > 0 = do
                                  (boardstate, b) <- ns 
                                  (newa, state, result )<- game logs s  boardstate b; 
                                  log $ printf "Game returns %f\n" result
                                  r1 <- randommove (BoardState [] [] 0)
                                  playtime newa (BoardState [] [] 0) (nextvalue logs X  r1 newa (BoardState [] [] 0)) (n - 1) (acc + result) r1

numruns :: IOArray Int Double ->Int -> Int -> Int -> IO()
numruns a n bins binsize  
  | n == 0 = printf "\nPlayed numruns times"
  | n > 0 = do
      arr <- newArray (0,bins) 0;
      b <- playrepeatedly a arr n bins binsize
      numruns b (n -1) bins binsize

playrepeatedly ::  IOArray Int Double ->IOArray Int Double -> Int -> Int -> Int -> IO(IOArray Int Double)
playrepeatedly a arr numrun numbins binsize = do 
 loop a 0 binsize
    where
      loop a i bs
        | i == numbins = let x = numrun
                             y = numbins
                             z = binsize in
                           loop1 a x 0 y z 
        | i < numbins = do
            v <- readthevalue arr i 
            writethevalue arr i (v+1)
            b <- playntimes a logs bs;
            loop b (i+1) bs
        where 
        loop1 a x j y z = if j < y
                              then do
                              fv <- readthevalue arr j
                              printf " Runs %f Final Value %f Binsize %d Numruns %d \n" (fv / fromIntegral( z * x)) fv z x
                              loop1 a x (j+1) y z
                              else
                              return a


main =  do
   p <- createarray
   ReinforcementLearning.numruns p 1 1 100
   return ()
```

I have updated another version that reuses the array that the algorithm uses to store the learnt values. I mean that this array is now returned and reused. I don't see any major improvement, though.

```
playntimes log n = do a <- createarray;
```

Comment: Types are there. Runs  even if a few aren't there.

Comment: "How do I get this code reviewed from the perspective of the learning improvement ? Not code quality." <- What's that even mean?

Comment: I will rephrase that. The Machine learning algorithm should improve its learning.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
gameplanrevised :: (String -> IO()) ->( IOArray Int Double) -> BoardState -> BoardState -> IO (IOArray Int Double,BoardState,Double) 
gameplanrevised log a state newstate = do 
                        exploremove a state newstate
                          where
                            exploremove :: ( IOArray Int Double) -> BoardState -> BoardState ->IO (IOArray Int Double,BoardState,Double)
                            exploremove a state newstate =
                              do
                                r <- randombetween;
                                let em = exploratorymove r in
                                  do
                                    result <- (terminalstatep log a (ReinforcementLearning.index newstate));
                                    case result of
                                      True -> do
                                        b <- update a state newstate
                                        valueofnewstate <- catch (readthevalue b (ReinforcementLearning.index newstate)) (\(SomeException e) -> print e >> mapM_ (putStr . show) [ (ReinforcementLearning.index newstate)]>> throwIO e)
                                        return (b,newstate,valueofnewstate)
                                      False -> do
                                        if em
                                          then do
                                            rm <- randommove newstate
                                            (nv,d) <- nextvalue logs O rm a newstate
                                            result1 <- (terminalstatep log d (ReinforcementLearning.index nv));
                                            valueofnewstate1 <-  catch (readthevalue d (ReinforcementLearning.index nv)) (\(SomeException e) -> print e >> mapM_ (putStr . show) [ (ReinforcementLearning.index nv)]>> throwIO e)
                                            if result1
                                              then do
                                              return (d,nv,valueofnewstate1)
                                              else do
                                              r1 <- randommove nv
                                              (ns,na) <- nextvalue logs X r1 d nv
                                              exploremove na nv ns 
                                          else do
                                            (gm,c) <- greedymove log a O newstate
                                            (nv',d') <- nextvalue logs O gm c newstate
                                            d'' <- update d' state nv'
                                            result2 <- (terminalstatep log d'' (ReinforcementLearning.index nv'));
                                            valueofnewstate2 <-  catch (readthevalue d'' (ReinforcementLearning.index nv')) (\(SomeException e) -> print e >> mapM_ (putStr . show) [ (ReinforcementLearning.index nv')]>> throwIO e)
                                            if result2
                                              then do
                                              return (d'',nv',valueofnewstate2)
                                              else do
                                              r1 <- randommove nv'
                                              (ns,na) <- nextvalue logs X r1 d'' nv'
                                              exploremove na nv' ns
```

This is the main function - 'gameplan' in the question - that was error prone. The function is recursive. There are two players, X and O who play the board game. So for each game of 'tictactoe', Player X gets the first chance and this player always makes a random move.  If Player X wins the game ends. Another game starts.

If Player X doesn't win, Player O gets a chance. O is smarter because O either makes a greedy move or a random move. If O wins its learning rate is accumulated and the next game starts. 'nextvalue' in the original question accumulates the rate. Rewards differ based on the result of the game.

After I fixed this function the learning rate improved. Sometimes O wins 70% of the time.

So I think I have answered it to my satisfaction. The code works well even though it has to improve its learning rate more.

I think Player O should become unbeatable and should win almost all the games.

Comment: All answers should contain a review of the code provided by the author or at least an insightful comment about how to improve it. Your answer as it currently stands does not contain either and is therefore not an acceptable answer.

Comment: Great that you reviewed your code yourself. If your interested in a review of your new `gameplan`, feel free to [ask for a review of your revised code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I think since it is a Machine Learning problem the code cannot be reviewed easily. Only people who know RL can do that. I didn't get answers because of that. Other specialized forums exist.